# AWS ElasticSearch 2.3 Java HTTP bulk API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm attampting to use a bulk HTTP api in Java on AWS ElasticSearch 2.3.
When I use a rest client for teh bulk load, I get the following error:

```
504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
```

When I run it as Lambda in Java, for HTTP Posts, I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-01-09T19:05:32.925Z 8e8164a7-d69e-11e6-8954-f3ac8e70b5be Task timed out after 15.00 seconds"
}
```

Through testing I noticed the bulk API doesn't work these with these settings:

```
    "number_of_shards" : 5,
    "number_of_replicas" : 5
```

When shards and replicas are set to 1, I can do a bulk load no problem.
I have tried using this setting to allow for my bulk load as well:

```
    "refresh_interval" : -1
```

but so far it made no impact at all. In Java Lambda, I load my data as an InputStream from S3 location.
What are my options at this point for Java HTTP?
Is there anything else in index settings I could try?
Is there anything else in AWS access policy I could try?
Thank you for your time.

## 1Edit:

I also have tried these params: _bulk?action.write_consistency=one&refresh  But makes no difference so far.

## 2Edit:

here is what made my bulk load work - set consistency param (I did NOT need to set refresh_interval):

```
            URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(myuri);
            uriBuilder = uriBuilder.addParameter("consistency", "one");                
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
            HttpEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(myInputStream);
            post.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the issue can occur when your index replication settings can not be satisfied by your cluster.  This happens either during a network partition, or if you simply set a replication requirement that can not be satisfied by your physical cluster.

In my case, this happens when I apply my production settings (number_of_replicas : 3) to my development cluster (which is single node cluster).

Your two solutions (setting the replica's to 1 Or setting your consistency to 1) resolve this issue because they allow Elastic to continue the bulk index w/o waiting for additional replica's to come online.

Elastic Search probably could have a more intuitive message on failure, maybe they do in Elastic 5.

Setting your cluster to a single